# How to render transparent faces on a cube - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, rendering

I'm trying to make a 3d environment in unity where there are many partially see-through cubes and cuboids. However, right now the cubes look like this:

[image]

Where it only shows the faces visible to the camera.
But I want it to show all faces, a bit like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can do this in unity? (I don't mind downloading shaders)

Comment: use a different shader / set your material to render backfaces

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is called Backface Culling, as explained here: (and in many other places) https://answers.unity.com/questions/1160848/backface-culling-off-for-unlit-transparent-shader.html

place Cull Off in your shader code (possibly ZWrite Off might be useful too)